# Arp poisoning with Ettercap makes the target unable to connect to sites

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arp

So I was messing around with Ettercap on my kali Linux and doing arp spoofing with my target machine being a mac laptop. After successfully poisoning the machine (checked with chk_poison) the machine is still connected to the internet but unable to connect to  any sites. For example if I try to go to YouTube the request just times out. When opening Wireshark on the target machine I see tons of TCP retransmissions which is what I think is making it unable to connect. Am I doing something wrong or is this common? (also if i am missing something I will add it)

Comment: How are you invoking ettercap? It has options that can disable its ability to forward the packets it captures via ARP poisoning attacks.

Comment: @Spiff I use sudo ettercap -G